# UIView on cell select

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Im trying to make a new UIView appear when a cell in the table is selected. I don't want to segue to a new View though. I just would like the area where the table currently is to be replaced by the new UIView. Is this possible to do and could anyone point in the right direction.

Comment: Take the effort to google it out. You just need to `addSubview` your new view on UITableView's `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` Method.

Comment: Been googling for the last hour and trying to do it myself for an hour before that. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UITableView's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method create a new view and `addsubview` the new view on top of the `UITableView`

```
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tableView.frame];
//customize new view
[self.view addSubview:newView];
tableView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: +1 Simple and elegant solution